# Can Rails automatically parse datetime received from form text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Can Rails automatically parse a datetime received from a form's text_field?

```
# in view
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :created_at %><br />
  <%= f.textfield :created_at %>
</div>

# in controller
params[:product][:updated_at].yesterday
```

Currently I'm get following error:

```
undefined method `yesterday' for "2010-04-28 03:37:00 UTC":String
```

Comment: Please show us your current code.

Comment: +1 for @ryan's request. It will be hard to help you without any actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are putting that param into a model directly, as the rails generator boilerplate code does, `ActiveRecord` takes care of that for you

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])
    @product.updated_at.yesterday #will succeed
    #rest of method
end
```

Other than that you are stuck with something like:

```
DateTime.parse(params[:product][:update_at])
```

or

```
DateTime.civil_from_format(:local, year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds)
```

But, in my experience `.civil_from_format` doesn't work as you'd expect with daylight savings time.