# rails: set datetime column using value in a text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

My question is similar to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809741/can-rails-automatically-parse-datetime-recieved-from-form-text-field) about putting data from a text_field into a datetime column.  It appears that I need to put the data into the text_field in a particular order or rails wont accept it.  Thing is, I can't always control how a user will input the data.  In fact, since I just added a JQuery datepicker the value that the user puts in will almost always be wrong.

I thought I could use Date.parse or Time.parse or DateTime.parse along with a setter method (mentioned in [railscast 32](http://railscasts.com/episodes/32-time-in-text-field)but that doesn't seem to be working for me either.  I keep getting an argument out of range error which also seems to be due to the input being in the wrong format.

Does anyone else use the JQuery datepicker to fill in a text field for the date?  What magic do you have to add to your model or controller to make it work?  Why is this so difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/timeliness) gem to overcome this problem and submit the date in the format I wanted. Along with timeliness I also used [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) to validate the date and time, that is it is not in future or anything.

To parse a string 'MM/DD/YYYY' using timeliness gem you would do:

```
Timeliness.parse(params[:my_date], :format => 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

The Time and Date parsers while they accept a wide variety of formats, can't figure out any time period you pass no matter what. If you get out of range errors, it means the format you used was invalid.

You can control the format that [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) uses and pick one that the time parser won't error on. The default MM/DD/YYYY should work fine thought, what format are you passing?

Comment: I am trying to pass MM/DD/YYYY but rails will only accept DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: For example, if I go into rails console and type Date.parse("25/07/2011") I get a valid response.  But if I type Date.parse("7/25/2011") I get an argument out of range error.

Comment: What version of Rails? I just tried on 3.0.7 and `Date.parse("7/25/2011")` returns a valid date for me. You can always modify the datepickers format by doing `dateFormat: "DD/MM/YYYY"` (see my link in the original answer) and that will make sure it always creates a date format that's valid for you in Rails.

Comment: Using rails 3.0.9.  Just to make sure there isn't a problem with my app, I created a new app from scratch, ran bundle, and then ran rails console.  I still wasn't able to Date.parse("7/25/2011")

Comment: I just rolled back to rails 3.0.7 and still wasn't able to Date.parse("7/25/2011").  I could take your advise and change the date format of the datepicker, but what if someone just types a date into the text box?  It really should be able to handle this date format.

Answer (score 0):

What if you switch the month and day fields before saving your object? You could do an onsubmit thing with jquery / javascript, or just use a date_select_tag and move the params around as you see fit in the controller before saving the object.

Other than that, there may be a rails default setting for the date format.  Not sure if you want to go so far as to change the date format for your entire application though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that rails/activerecord expect the date to be in ISO format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. But this not a user-friendly format

The easiest solution in my opinion is using the alt attribute on the datepicker - Basically, show a date format but submit another date format:

```
  = f.text_field :your_date, id: "your_date", class: "hidden" // This is hidden
  // This will show up
  = text_field_tag "date[something_we_will_not_use]", f.object.your_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
    class: "datepicker", 'data-alt-field' => '#your_date'
```

**Datepicker initialization**

```
$('.datepicker').each(function() {

      var alt_field = $(this).attr('data-alt-field');

      $this.datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
        altField: alt_field, // This is the tag where the date will be filled
        altFormat: "yy/mm/dd" // This is how the date will be posted to your controller
      });
    })
```